# Access a Json file from a utility dll on a child folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dll

I'm having trouble accessing a Json file from within a dll in a subfolder.
Basically this dll needs to get some information from the json file.

Locally I'm able to do it using absolute path, but I couldn't do it with virtual path.

Should I give the path starting from the dll location going up to the json file or use the path from my webapplication global directory and how?

**Code:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); //Get info from Json file string value = 
client.DownloadString(@"..\..\WebUIProjects\WebAPI\MimeDetec‌​tiveResources\MimeDe‌​tectiveConfiguration‌​.json");
```

**Exception:**

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\MimeDetectiveResources\MimeDete‌​ctiveConfiguration.j‌​son'

Many thanks

Comment: Please add more details. Are you having an exception?

Comment: Please post the current code that you are using and any exception you encounter.

Comment: Hello,

I'm trying to access using something like that 
WebClient client = new WebClient();

          
          //Get info from Json file
          string value = client.DownloadString(@"..\..\WebUIProjects\WebAPI\MimeDetectiveResources\MimeDetectiveConfiguration.json");
and I have an exception of 
Message
:
"Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\MimeDetectiveResources\MimeDetectiveConfiguration.json

Comment: Is this a subfolder beaneath your virtual path? You should just use File.Open or [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of WebClient. Also, check out [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for resolving the relative path.

Comment: Hello,
I was actually looking to do something like that.
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Resources\Configuration.json");
Now it is workign correctly. Thank you